# What examples are there of suits blurring the lines between powered armor and mecha in hard sci-fi?

Tags: hard-sci-fi, mecha

TVTropes has two different entries on [Mini-Mecha](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MiniMecha) and [Powered Armor](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PoweredArmor), where the former is "something that is piloted" and the latter is "something that is worn". Now, listed in both pages are examples of things which are supposedly halfway between the two concepts, but most of them have no size estimate. So, what is the biggest powered armor / smallest mecha (meant to be used by average-sized humans) that you can think of in hard sci-fi? Is there anything about 8 feet / 2.5 m tall?

Comment: Interesting question, though I have to say the TV Tropes listing is very extensive - albeit without size info.

Comment: I fear this question to be list-inducing.

Comment: I agree with SQB. Also, while this questions seems to live from the fact that there is no real distinction between the two, it asks for examples from both specific groups. Which makes it a highly opinion-based discussion, at best.

Comment: Interesting question. I don't think there's a definitive answer about where the line is drawn. For me it would probably be at the point of automation and bulk. If it has actuator extensions and joysticks, it's probably Mini-Mecha. If you have to 'climb into it' as oppose to 'put it on', it's Mini-Mecha.

Answer (score 3):

From the top of my mind:

- The working suit in Aliens is about 3 m tall.
- The armor of the marines and other infantry in StarCraft is about 2.5 m tall.

I've invented a new criterion for separating them: if the person's fingers fit inside the machine fingers, it is a powered armor. if it has fully robotic fingers or not fingers at all, it is a mecha/mini-mecha.

With that in mind, both of my previous examples are mini-mechas. Generally speaking, any machine of more than 2.5 m will have independent fingers, or else it will need to have very short arms -in proportion- for the user to reach the mechanic hands.

Comment: This is a sensible criteria, but sometimes the limbs don't even fit inside the robot's limbs. Ironman's fingers fit inside the glove's fingers, but Ironmonger from the same movie obviously didn't even fit human limbs in robot limbs. That might be the better cutoff point.

Comment: @JohnO: Well, Ironmonger is _obviously_ a mini-mecha, isn't it? ;-) The problem with the limbs is that you may fit them only partially, or only the arms, or only the legs... so you might have a half-mecha or something...

Comment: Good point. Anyway, not disputing your criteria, it's definitely the right idea... just quibbling over the details.

Comment: Its like trying to define precisely when a netbook becomes a laptop. There is no where you can place the division, there has to be some field of overlap for such things I think.

Comment: @Nick Of course it's going to be arbitrary, but I don't think that we can't come to a consensus on it. I suggest that the existence of two different terms implies that we've already got sort of an collective, unconscious idea that there is a distinction and a vague sense of what that is. We might be able to hammer out the details here if we try.

Comment: Not sure if you mean the marines have their fingers in the suit's fingers in SC2. But that's not the case! [Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tYFzOcy0Db4#t=2m56s) at about 2:56

Comment: @WillF: What I mean is that the user fingers are _not_ in the armor fingers, so using my criterion, they are mechas. There are a lot of places, like the one you linked, where you can see that the user hands are in the middle of the armor fore-arm.

Comment: Actually the marines in SC do, if you watch the opening credits of wings of liberty when tycus is put into his suit it shows his fingers going into the glove before being screwed in